# How to eliminate public listing of my email address?

Tags: email, search, spam-prevention

I get way too much junk mail that I am not thinking of ditching my email address. I am think it is in part because my email is publicly listed somewhere?

Can I search my email listing on google etc so I can remove it?

For example I was once member of a sports club (website) and may have collected junk because of that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple solution to this. The cat is out of the bag (website with your email address).

You can change your email address but if you use it in public, it gets out. Buy stuff, talk to businesses and so on.

Then spammers get address books from people with unsecured systems ("I don't need a password - I am much too smart to let anything happen") and that causes huge amounts of spam.

The only effective way I have found is top notch spam filtering and grey listing (dumping mail where the sender cannot be found). Most big outfits have some form of grey listing.

I use Mail.com and it is top notch.

So the answer is to stop the spam, not change email addresses as that action will not last very long.